# Is this a jQuery variable? "fadesettings: {overduration: 350, outduration: 100}"

Tags: jquery, variables

I tried searching for 'fadesettings' in jQuery but I can't seem to find any. I found the code:

```
fadesettings: {overduration: 350, outduration: 100}
```

inside a jquery variable and I am not sure how to interpret it.

The part of the code looks something like this

```
var jquerycssmenu={

fadesettings: {overduration: 350, outduration: 100}, //duration of fade in/ out animation, in milliseconds

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a user defined JSON array with two variables declared in there: `overduration`, and `outduration`. I assume those are used somewhere later. It's not specific to jQuery per se, but can certainly be used to pass variable into a jQuery function. Something like this:

```
fadeIn(jquerycssmenu.fadesettings.overduration)
```

where `fadeIn` is a jQuery effect, and the settings, are coming from the array variable found in `overduration` inside `jquerycssmenu.fadesettings`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a jQuery variable.

It's an object literal, that has an object literal as a property.

(Judging from the naming it's probably used for some animation method in the jQuery library, or a method in some jQuery plugin.)

You would get the same object using this code:

```
var fade = new Object();
fade.overduration = 350;
fade.outduration = 100;

var jquerycssmenu = new Object();
jquerycssmenu.fadesettings = fade;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an object, you can get it's value by the following.

`console.log(jquerycssmenu.fadesettings); // {overduration: 350, outduration: 100}`
`console.log(jquerycssmenu.fadesettings.overduration); // 350`

Answer (score 1):

It's not part of the jQuery library. It looks like it was part of some sample menu code from the dynamic drive website.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddlevelsmenu/